# Iphone. Create a latitude from a string or integers

Tags: iphone, string, latitude-longitude

One small conversion problem that drives me crazy.

I have a string (ex "35.453454") that represents a latitude.
I want to use it as a latitude for CLLocation.

How can I convert the string in the proper CLLocation (in degrees) format ?

Many thanks, this drives me so mad !
Thomas

Answer (score 50):

To convert an NSString to CLLocationDegrees (which is `double`):

```
return [theString doubleValue];
```

Comment: I´ve been fooling around for hours but this is simple and effective. thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

Lets assume that you have stored your string `"35.453454"` as

**In Objective C**

`NSString *latitudeString = @"35.453454";`

**In Swift 2.2**

```
let latituteString : String = "35.453454"
```

And you want to convert this NSString to proper CLLocation.

***But CLLocation has two parameter latitude and longitude respectively.***

Unless, you don't have a longitude corresponding to your given latitude "35.453454" is it not possible to store just you latitude in CLLocation.

**CASE 1 :** Assume that you don't have corresponding longitude. Then, you can store your only latitude in CLLocationDegrees for the time being to later use it in initializing your CLLocation object.

**In Objective-C :**

```
CLLocationDegress myLatitude = [latitudeString doubleValue];
```

**In Swift 2.2**

```
let myLatitute : CLLocationDegress = Double(latitudeString)
```

**CASE 2 :** Assume that you have corresponding longitude. Then, you can store your both latitude and longitude in CLLocationDegrees to use it in initializing your CLLocation object.

Let your longitude be `18.9201344`

then,

**In Objective-C**

```
NSString *longitudeString = @"18.9201344";

//creating latitude and longitude for location
CLLocationDegrees latitudeDegrees = [latitudeString doubleValue];
CLLocationDegrees longitudeDegrees = [longitudeString doubleValue];

//initializing location with respective latitude and longitude
CLLocation *myLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:latitudeDegrees longitude:longitudeDegrees];
```

**In Swift 2.2**

```
let longitudeString : String = "18.9201344"

    let latitudeDegrees : CLLocationDegrees = Double(latitudeString)
    let longitudeDegrees : CLLocationDegress = Double(longitudeString)

    let location : CLLocation = CLLocation.init(latitude: latitudeDegrees, longitude: longitudeDegrees)
```